# mysql - select distinct mutually exclusive (based on another column's value) rows

Tags: mysql, sql

First off, I would like to say that if after reading the question, anyone has a suggestion on a more informative title for this question, please tell me, as I think mine is somewhat lacking, now, on to business...

Given this table structure:

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account | varchar(20)                         | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| domain  | varchar(100)                        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status  | enum('FAILED','PENDING','COMPLETE') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And this data:

```
+----+---------+------------------+----------+
| id | account | domain           | status   |
+----+---------+------------------+----------+
|  1 | jim     | somedomain.com   | COMPLETE |
|  2 | bob     | somedomain.com   | COMPLETE |
|  3 | joe     | somedomain.com   | COMPLETE |
|  4 | frank   | otherdomain.com  | COMPLETE |
|  5 | betty   | otherdomain.com  | PENDING  |
|  6 | shirley | otherdomain.com  | FAILED   |
|  7 | tom     | thirddomain.com  | FAILED   |
|  8 | lou     | fourthdomain.com | COMPLETE |
+----+---------+------------------+----------+
```

I would like to select all domains which have a 'COMPLETE' status for all accounts (rows).

Any domains which have a row containing any value other then 'COMPLETE' for the status must not be returned.

So in the above example, My expected result would be:

```
+------------------+
| domain           |
+------------------+
| somedomain.com   |
| fourthdomain.com |
+------------------+
```

Obviously, I can achieve this by using a sub-query such as:

```
mysql> select distinct domain from test_table where status = 'complete' and domain not in (select distinct domain from test_table where status != 'complete'); 
+------------------+
| domain           |
+------------------+
| somedomain.com   |
| fourthdomain.com |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will work fine on our little mock-up test table, but in the real situation, the tables in question will be tens (or even hundreds) of thousands of rows, and I'm curious if there is some *more efficient* way to do this, as the sub-query is slow and intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
select domain
from   test_table
group by domain
having sum(case when status = 'COMPLETE'
                then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Please see my comment in your answer.

Comment: +1 Apparently performs v. well, and is sweet/simple to boot.  Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.  Effectively just joins two basic queries together, then compares their count.

```
select
    main.domain
from 
    your_table main

    inner join 
    (
        select 
            domain, count(id) as cnt
        from 
            your_table
        where 
            status = 'complete'
        group by 
            domain
    ) complete
    on complete.domain = main.domain

group by
    main.domain

having
    count(main.id) = complete.cnt
```

You should also ensure you have an index on `domain` as this relies on a join on that column.

Comment: While this method does perform better then the sub-query, I chose the other answer because it performs considerably better then this one. On a table with 10k rows, your query performed the operation in 5.56 seconds and the other answer took 0.11.

Comment: @jesse_galley Sorry about the mistake - was hand written in a text editor. Fair enough re performance, looks like mySql must implement the `case` over each row in the final result very quickly... or do some clever optimisation. I've actually simplified it now, so dunno if you're interested in checking it again.  Not sure it will be any faster though, but might be worth a quick check.  But certainly can't match the other answer for sweet simplicity! Good luck with it. +1 for the question, by the way.  Well asked.